# No puedo juntar 2 listas, el tiro de carácter es lista no str, aun asi me aparece el error "can only concatenate list (not "str") to list"

Tags: python

data2
print(type(data2))
print(type(months))

<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>

Lista_completa2 = []
for i in range(Cantidad):
Lista_completa2.append(data2[i]+ months[i])

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[149], line 3
1 Lista_completa2 = []
2 for i in range(Cantidad):
----> 3     Lista_completa2.append(data2[i]+ months[i])

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Answer (score 0):

Mil disculpas, ya he resuelto el problema, solo bebia poner un corchete atras de months.

Por favor hacer caso omiso a esta pregunta

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).